# how to get integer value from strings.xml in android

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I call the real value integer from res/values/stings.xml like below

```
<integer name="GUI_OK">0x9001</integer>
<integer name="GUI_Error">0x9002</integer>
```

R.Integer.GUI_OK is an int(2131230720) not the real value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't put them in `strings.xml`. Put them in `integers.xml`.

Second, you should use `context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.GUI_OK)`, where `context` is an instance of a Context object, such as an Activity or Service.

`R.integer.GUI_OK` is simply a resource value which Android uses to retrieve the actual value of that resource.